# oops design feature vs other programming models

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am going through the concepts of OOPS and I am wondering what is the unique design feature that makes Object Oriented Programming different than other 
programming models ?

- It uses mathematical logic for computer programming.
- It describes the desired outcome of a program without explicitly listing the steps that need to be carried out.
- It specifies the steps the program must take to reach the desired state.
- It is broken down into discrete units capable of receiving messages, processing data, and sending messages onto other units.

I am stuck on this question.

Comment: This is a poor question, both the question in your exercise that you are asking about and your post here on SO

Comment: This question needs some improvement before it's considered on-topic: "*4. Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.***" - [What can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - Might wanna spruce up your post before the amount of downvotes grow

Answer (score 1):

•  It presents a **simple, clear and easy** to maintain structure.

•  It enhances program **modularity** since each object exists independently.

•  **New features** can be easily added without disturbing the existing one.

• **component-specific behavior** - making details on how to handle a particular component the responsibility of the smaller component-specific machine ensures any time that component is handled, its machine will do so appropriately;

• **polymorphic expressions** - because component-specific machines performs operations tailored to its particular component, the same message sent to different machines can act differently;

• **type abstraction** - it often makes sense for several different types of components to use the same vocabulary for the operations their machines do;

• **separation of concerns** - leaving component-specific details to their machines means the process machine only needs to handle the more general, larger concerns of its process and the data required to manage it; plus, it's less likely to be affected by changes in other components;

• **adaptability** - components that focus on their area of speciality can be adapted to unforeseen use simply by changing the components it uses, or making it available to another process machine;

• **code reuse** - components with a narrow focus and greater adaptability can leverage their development cost by being put to use more often.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's trying to answer a question for a quiz, and he needs to choose one of the bullet points he listed in his answer, not create your own bullet points describing OOP.

Comment: @VinceEmigh This is a much better answer than just picking one of the bullets in the question.

Comment: @VinceEmigh thanks for warning, I just wanted to help

Comment: @puhlen Yes, but this is a multiple choice quiz, which means the OP needs to choose one of the points they listed. If you asked a multiple choice question, you wouldn't want answers that weren't within the answer list. This question is somewhat off-topic, as it can be considered homework help without any proof of effort or research. But that doesn't mean we should give answers that dodge the question in hopes for rep. I understand this question wasn't detailed, that's why I commented - Murat probably didn't realize it's multiple choice. Each choice represents a paradigm, only one is OOP.